# ArgumentError: missing required workbook file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, gemfile, roo

I am trying to read an Excel file in Rails using Roo.

```
file = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(path, extension: :xlsx)
```

On this line I'm getting this error `ArgumentError: missing required workbook file from /home/riya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/roo-2.8.3/lib/roo/excelx/workbook.rb:23:in 'initialize'`

I checked the workbook on this path and it's alright.
Not getting what could be the error.

Comment: Works with `Ruby 2.6.3` and `Ruby 2.7.2`, you could try to update Ruby.

Comment: Did you check that a `roo_workbook.xml` file is generated in the tmp directory? https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/master/lib/roo/excelx/shared.rb#L27

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer Yes, I checked the path. It's there in the .tmp directory.

Comment: @eux But the documentation says it works on different versions. Mine is `Ruby 2.6.0`